# Using Apache VirtualHosts to serve multiple subdomains from same global ip address

Tags: apache, apache2, subdomain, virtualhost

I have a domain `myexample.com` which I would like to have multiple subdomains for, using the same IP address. I want to use Apache VirtualHosts without showing the client that redirection is happening. Here are the rules I want:
`www.myexample.com gets content from the /var/www folder`
`www1.myexample.com gets content from the /var/www1 folder`
`www2.myexample.com gets content from the /var/www2 folder`
The problem here is that all three must run on the same computer all on port 80 and I don't want to use 301 redirection because then the client can see what is happening. How do I configure VirtualHosts to do this? I can't figure out how to use mod_rewrite. Im running Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add virtual hosts it is recommendable to write each virtual host in a separate file or write all of the virtual hosts for a specific user in one file. This improves the manageability of your server and makes it easy for you to find which file to edit when you want to change a specific setting for 1 domain.

When editing your `apache2.conf` file in `/etc/apache2` there should be a line that says `include sites-enabled/` at the bottom of your file. If it isn't there add it.

then create a new file for either your domain or your user in the `sites-enabled` folder. For easy editing I would do `nano <filename>.conf` which will open the editor and set the filename and extension.

Insert the following [code](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) into the file.

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>
    ServerName www1.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@www1.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www1
</VirtualHost>
```

To get everything on the same IP you could either enter *:80 in place of `0.0.0.0` to listen on all IP's on the system or enter the specific public IP address the server has for enhanced security.

Also, other directives may be required if you want to set specific PHP values or if you want to move your log files to a different file use:

```
CustomLog custompath/domainname.log
ErrorLog custompath/domainname.error.log
```

Hopes that solves your problem